# Eta-squared from Kruskal-Wallis in R

Tags: anova, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test, z-statistic, generalized-eta-squared

Is it possible to calculate Eta-squared from Kruskal-Wallis test results? I know how to do it by hand for the ANOVA or Mann-Whitney using the Z-statistics, but i must use the KW test for my current data. The KW test using the "kruskal.test" function gives a "Chi-squared" value instead of Z-statistics, so i am not sure how to do it by hand.

I need to make conclusions that "factor (X) explains ___ of the variance in Y". So producing Eta-squared (or similar) is necessary.

Thank you

Comment: You can't say much about the variance since it is a rank-based test.

Comment: What makes you say you *must* do a Kruskal-Wallis test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an effect size statistic for the Kruskal-Wallis test called "eta-squared".  For the calculation, see Tomczak and Tomczak ( http://tss.awf.poznan.pl/files/3_Trends_Vol21_2014__no1_20.pdf ).  This statistic is in fact based on the H statistic, not the z value.  However, as @michaelm points out, the interpretation of this "eta-squared" will not be about the variance.  I have some reluctance about this statistic, and the related epsilon-squared, as it seems that most readers don't have a good sense of how to interpret the value.  There are other options for effect size statistics.  My recommendation would be pairwise or maximum Vargha and Delaney's *A*.  There's some discussion of effect size statisitcs for KW here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Anyone_know_how_to_calculate_eta_squared_for_a_Kruskal-Wallis_analysis .